# ModuleNotFoundError Django

Tags: python, django, pycharm, python-venv

After having setup a venv and starting a project getting the correct files (which i have double checked). i see that in the files the import statements are not working. `views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def home (request):
    return HttpResponse('<h1>header</h1>')
# Create your views here.
```

When running it returns this error:

`from django.shortcuts import render
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'`

`urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from migrations import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="header")
]
```

Which returns this error:

> ```
>   from django.contrib import admin   
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
> ```

Every project file's import statements for django have the red wavy underlining in pycharm meaning it cant find the module. How could I fix this and what could I have done wrong?
Haven't found anything useful on the internet yet.

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment? If you are, is it active?

Comment: @RHSmith159 I do have a virtual environment, am I only able to run the files from cmd (I'm on windows) or could I still use Pycharm? if so, how could i activate the venv in pycharm?

Comment: You should be able to configure pycharm to use the virtual environment, its been a few years since I've used pycharm so I'm not sure exactly how to do this, but hopefully this will put you on the right track: `https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html?keymap=primary_default`

Comment: hit pip freeze or pip3 freeze command check weather django is installed on your system or not

Comment: @RHSmith159 Worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had not activated the venv in Pycharm. To do this: hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> go to projects\project-interpreter then hit the "gear" Icon on the right-side of the window and click add.

From here you can create a new venv or configure an existing one. Special thanks to @RHSmith159 for giving the answer in the comments.